# Mathematica gives wrong answer to integral of $\ln(x^x)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate $\int \ln\left(x^x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x$.

It seems that the result is wrong since integrating first and then taking derivative, the result should be the original function, but it's not.

It seems that `D[Log[x]*0.5*x^2 - 1/4*x^2, x]` should be the correct answer.

Am I wrong or does Mathematica have a problem?

```
Integrate[Log[x^x], x]
(* -(1/4) x (x + 2 x Log[x] - 4 Log[x^x]) *)

Integrate[Log[Power[x, x]], x]
(* -(1/4) x (x + 2 x Log[x] - 4 Log[x^x]) *)

D[Log[x]*0.5*x^2 - 1/4*x^2, x]
(* 0. + 1. x Log[x] *)

D[Integrate[Log[Power[x, x]], x], x]
(* -(1/4) x (3 + 2 Log[x] - 4 (1 + Log[x])) + 
 1/4 (-x - 2 x Log[x] + 4 Log[x^x]) *)
```

Comment: `D[Integrate[Log[Power[x, x]], x], x] // Together`

Comment: Do you understand that $x\log x=\log{x^x}$? *Mathematica* considers $x\log x$ simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
D[Integrate[Log[Power[x, x]], x], x] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &

(*  x Log[x]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: +1 Note that the assumption is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Just take the definition

```
Log[x^x] := Log[ Exp[ x Log[x] ] = x Log[x] /; -Pi < Arg[x] < Pi
```

Intgration by parts

```
Integrate[ x Log[x] ,x]  == x^2/2 Log[x] - Integrate[x/2 ,x] == x^2/2 Log[x] - x^2/4 

 D[ x^2/2 Log[x] - x^2/4  ,x]] == x Log[x] +x/2 - x/2
```

Of course you are free to rewrite logarithms with factors as logs of powers

```
  x^2/2 Log[x] == x^2 Log[Sqrt[x]] == Log[x^(x^2/2)
```